# Swift generate 15 random digits

Tags: swift

I want to generate a username with random digits, I can generate just one digit by doing `let randomInt = Int.random(in: 10..<26)`, but how can I generate multiple digits?

EX: user19384845324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made one function for generate random string

```
func getAlphaNumericRandomNumber() -> NSMutableString
{
    let letters : NSString = "0123456789"
    
    let randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: 10)
    
    let reversedRandomAccessCollection = (0 ... 14).reversed() //Here You can change range for how many digit you want
    
    for _ in reversedRandomAccessCollection
    {
        let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
        randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.character(at: Int(rand)))
    }
    
    return randomString
}
```

You can use this as below

```
let randomString = self.getAlphaNumericRandomNumber()
let name = "user\(randomString)"
print(name)
```

Here is output

[image]

Comment: Why `NS(Mutable)String`? Swift `String` is mutable by default as `var`iable.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random number between 1 and 999_999_999_999_999, convert it to string and add 15 zeros - the number of digits of the random number:

```
var randomUser: String {
    let value = String(Int.random(in: 1...999_999_999_999_999))
    return "user" + repeatElement("0", count: 15-value.count) + value
}
```

---

```
let user = randomUser  // "user837904153733798"
```

Answer (score 0):

created a function to accept number of digit and return the random number

```
func randomString(_ n: Int) -> String {

let digits = "1234567890"
return String(Array(0..<n).map { _ in digits.randomElement()! })

}

let randomNumber = randomString(15)
let name = "name\(randomNumber)"
print(name)
```